# Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability Tweedie Notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I am trying to understand the notation used in the MC and Stochastic Stability book. Specifically, on page 63.

If I have a markov chain $\Phi$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P_{\mu})$

where $\Omega$=$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}X_i$ where $X$ is a general state space  and $P_\mu$ is the probability measure for $\Phi$ with initial distribution $\mu$ defined for $X$. The notation I am having trouble understanding is the following:

$$\mathbb{E}_\mu[\theta^{n}H|\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n]=\mathbb{E}_{\Phi_n}[H]$$

where H is a bounded measurable function on $\Omega$ and $\theta^n$ is the shift operator and $\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n=\sigma(\Phi_0,\Phi_1,...,\Phi_n)\subset \mathcal{B}(X^{n+1})$.

Firstly, it is my understanding that
$$\mathbb{E}_\mu[H|\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n]$$
is a random variable that is $\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n$ measurable  but agrees with $H=h(\Phi_0,\Phi_1,...)$ on all $A\in\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n$ with respect to expectation. But is it not required that $\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n\subset \mathcal{F}$ in order for the expectation to make sense?

Secondly, $\theta^{n}H=h(\Phi_n,\Phi_{n+1},...)$ then

$$\mathbb{E}_\mu[\theta^{n}H|\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n]=\mathbb{E}_\mu[h(\Phi_n,\Phi_{n+1},...)|\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n]$$

I am assuming that somehow independence follows from the sigma algebra and then by time homogeneity of the markov chain then can use $\Phi_n$ as the starting value but this is where I get lost as to what this notation means:

$$\mathbb{E}_{\Phi_n}[H]$$

or the equation
$$\mathbb{E}_\mu[\theta^{n}H|\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n]$$

in general.

Comment: Related (to your second question in particular) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496752/proof-of-strong-markov-property-check

Comment: $\Bbb E_{\Phi_n}[H]$ is the random variable $g(\Phi_n)$, where $g(x) :=\Bbb E_x[H]$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Can you help clarify this notation $\mathbb{E}_\mu[\theta^{n}H|\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n]$. It is my understanding that $\mathcal{F}^{\Phi}_n$ is most likely a filtration system on $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(X^{\infty})$  but the book states its a subset $\mathcal{B}(X^{n+1})$. That notation only makes sense to me if we are working on a subset of $\mathcal{F}$ which is not a subset of  $\mathcal{B}(X^{n+1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal F^\Phi_n$ is $\sigma\{\Phi_0,\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_n\}$. Each $A\in \mathcal F^\Phi_n$ can be represented as $\{\omega\in X^\infty: (\Phi_0(\omega,\ldots,\Phi_n(\omega))\in B\}$, where $B\in\mathcal B(X^{n+1})$. Thus $A=B\times X\times X\times\cdots$, so perhaps the text is identifying  $A$ with $B$ in thinking of $A$ as a subset of $\mathcal B(X^{n+1})$.